# Run while in PHP

Tags: php, html, time, notifications, text-files

Im not a PHP programmer but for me to get the job done, I did a few researches and I was able to achieve my goal... well partially

What the program does is: 
It reads a txt file that has a content like this:

Dishwasher is finished and ready. Jun 22, 2016 - 9:15 PM

Front door is been opened. Jun 22, 2016 - 8:39 PM

Front door is been opened. Jun 22, 2016 - 9:55 AM

So what I tried to do is to change the time and date for " 33 minutes ago" " 2 days ago" for each line and process one by one to display as echo on the page.

So I had to create something like this:

$first_part = The text in the beginning example "Dishwasher is finished and ready."

$second_part = The text in between the code "Jun 22, 2016 - 9:15 PM" and convert this to "10 minutes ago" or whatever time is...

Then join those two variables as one and display in echo.

But I need to run all of this again for the first 2 lines, not the whole file.

So the code I have its working PERFECT if its only one time, but if I put the while command, the page displays blank.
So if I can get a help just to get the while on this whole process to work, it would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Here is my code:

```
    $monthyr = date('Ym');
    $filename = $monthyr . "_notification" . ".txt"; //Every month the filename      changes to YYYYmm_notification.txt//
    $file = fopen($filename,"r");
    $content = fgets($file);
    $i = 1;
```

while($i <= 2)     //Here where the problem is, when I use this string//
{

$string = $content;
$substring = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "<"));


function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
    }

$fullstring = $content;
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '<div id="time">', '</div>');



$time = strtotime($parsed);

$ago = humanTiming($time).' ago';
function humanTiming ($time)
{

    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
    $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
);

foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
    if ($time < $unit) continue;
    $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
    return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
}

}
echo " " . $substring  . $ago . "<br />";

$i++;
}

fclose($file); 
</pre></code>

Comment: Blank page is usually a server error. Is there anything in your error log?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you declare multiple times the functions `humanTiming()` and `get_string_between()` since they are inside the `while` loop. Move the declarations outside the loop and it should work.

It would be helpful if you could post the error log.

Answer (score 0):

you should fix at least the following

put the functions at the end

enter the  the "$content = fgets($file)" into the loop because the loop is worthless if you dont read from the file lines

the $i variable is not useful , it looks like you tried to build a "for" loop instead of a while.

I changed it here only for an example so you can continue to work on it and see what i meant:

```
@$monthyr = date('Ym');
$filename = $monthyr . "_notification" . ".txt"; 
$filename = "input.txt";
$file = fopen($filename,"r");

while($content = fgets($file)) {

    $substring = substr($content, 0, strpos($content, "<"));

    $fullstring = $content;
    $parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '<div id="time">', '</div>');

    @$time = strtotime($parsed);
    $ago = humanTiming($time).' ago';
    echo " " . $substring  . $ago . "<br />\n";
}

fclose($file);




function humanTiming ($time){

    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
    $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }

}



function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

Comment: Did you check the answer ? Did it helped you ?